# Getting User Tweets into Processing successfully - Twitter4j

Tags: twitter, processing, twitter4j

Managed to finally get my own tweets into **Processing**, using the following code and the twitter4j library. I've now been trying to adapt the code to pull in the tweets of a specific user, without any luck, regardless of the many people online who have posted 'working code'. Could someone steer me right and show me what exactly needs to be altered? Thanks!

```
import twitter4j.util.*;
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.management.*;
import twitter4j.api.*;
import twitter4j.conf.*;
import twitter4j.json.*;
import twitter4j.auth.*;
import java.util.*;

List<Status>statuses = null;

TwitterFactory twitterFactory;
Twitter twitter;

void setup() {     
  size(100, 100);    
  background(0); 

  connectTwitter();    
  getTimeline();  
}  

void draw() {     
  background(0);
}  

// Initial connection
void connectTwitter() {  
  ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();  
  cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXX");
  cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXX");
  cb.setOAuthAccessToken("XXXX");
  cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XXXX"); 

  twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());    
  twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance();  

  println("connected");
} 

// Get your tweets
void getTimeline() {     
  try {        
    statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline();
  }   
  catch(TwitterException e) {         
    println("Get timeline: " + e + " Status code: " + e.getStatusCode());
  }     
  for (Status status:statuses) {               
    println(status.getUser().getName() + ": " + status.getText());
  }
}
```

EDIT - Amended code to get User Tweets. Produces no errors or results...

```
void getUserTimeLine(long stephenfry) {
  try {
    ResponseList<Status> statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(stephenfry);
  }
  catch(TwitterException e) {
    println("Get timeline: " + e + " Status code: " + e.getStatusCode());
  }
    for (Status status : statuses) {
        System.out.println(status.getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add following to your code to retrieve any users timeline-

```
void getUserTimeLine(long userID/*You can also use screenName*/) {
    ResponseList<Status> statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(userID/*You can also use screenName*/);
    for (Status status : statuses) {
        System.out.println(status.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I added your code to mine, but with no luck. I got a 'Twitter Exception' error, so I wrapped it in a try and catch. But though when I run it I now don't get any errors, I also don't get any of the Specific User tweets? - I've added your amended code as an edit to the original post. Any ideas?

Comment: What was the exception you were getting without try/catch?

Comment: It was - 'Unhandled exception type TwitterException' - Any ideas?

Comment: what version of twitter4j lib are you using?

Comment: twitter4j 4.0.2 is the version I'm using.